# how to show a date as label on a JSF button in customized format?

Tags: java, jsf

how to show `Date`(or `Timestamp`) in customized format on JSF `<h:commandButton>` ?

I'm using JSF 1.1

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are standard ways for that, so please search and try first.

Comment: Are you trying to format a date or do you want to use the date in a string (e.g. `Go to 2013`)?

Comment: <h:commandButton styleClass="dateButtonStyle" value="#{amendDate}" action="#{myBackingBean.myMethod}"> <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" type="date" timeZone="IST" dateStyle="short"/> </h:commandButton>. I was trying to do like this

Comment: @kostja: there are actually no "standard ways" for this. At least not in standard JSF 1.1.

Comment: @BalusC - I am quite sure to have seen a `convertDateTime` element in a JSF 1.x project. It may have been 1.2 though. Was it introduced after 1.1 or is it not to be considered the standard way?

Comment: @kostja: It doesn't work in `<h:commandButton>`. It works in `UIOutput` components only (which also includes `UIInput` components, but not `UICommand` components).

Comment: I have to apologize for my first comment. The question provided no hint of research and I was too sure :) It turns out I was wrong

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The JSF `<h:commandButton>` doesn't support a converter, neither does it support any text children. You'd *either* need to perform the job in some helper backing bean method,

```html
<h:commandButton ... value="#{bean.dateInCustomizedFormat}" />
```

with

```
public String getDateInCustomizedFormat() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
}
```

*or* create a reuseable custom EL function for this:

```html
<%@taglib prefix="my" uri="http://example.com/el/functions" %>
...
<h:commandButton ... value="#{my:formatDate(bean.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}" />
```

with

```
package com.example.el;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public final class Functions{

    private Functions() {
        // Hide constructor.
    }

    public static String formatDate(Date date, String pattern) {
        Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
        return new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, locale).format(date);
    }

}
```

and a `/WEB-INF/functions.tld` (given JSF 1.1, I'll assume that you're still on JSP, not Facelets):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>Custom Functions</short-name>
    <uri>http://example.com/el/functions</uri>

    <function>
        <name>formatDate</name>
        <function-class>com.example.el.Functions</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String formatDate(java.util.Date, java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

*(note: if you're using Servlet 2.4/JSP 2.0, replace `2_1` and `2.1` by `2_0` and `2.0` respectively)*